# soft Keyboard hides edittext when singleline property set to true

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have some `EditText` components when an EditText gains focus the keyboard hides it.
After I start typing then the edittext rises above the keyboard.

I have the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the activity tag in the manifest.

This is the style i'm using for the `EditText`

```
<style name="info_style">
    <item name="android:textColor">#5a5959</item>
    <item name="android:maxEms">10</item>

    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/info_height</item>

    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSize</item>
</style>
```

When I remove the `android:singleLine` property it works fine and the `EditText` appears above the keyboard, but it is needed for the next button to be shown on the soft keyboard while typing.